# How do I count the number of instances a string/sub-string appears in the filenames of a certain directory in Unix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, directory, filenames

Say my current working directory is called my_dir and I have a few different files in them:

```
file1
file_dog
filedog_1
dog_file
```

How do I count the number of instances "dog" appears (should be 3) in my directory?

Thank you!

Comment: Actually, the title for the question implies that you could also have
dog-eat-dog
as a match (2 instances of "dog") - but neither of the suggested solutions counts that as 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -c option from grep

```
grep -c:
   Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.

ls -1 | grep -c dog
```

or:

```
ls -1 *[dD][oO][gG]* | wc -l
```

Comment: Thank you grep -c worked perfectly and is also sweet and simple!

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works even if filenames contain newline characters:

```
$ touch  file1 file_dog filedog_1 dog_file
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*dog*' -print0 | grep -zc .
3
```

How it works:

- `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*dog*' -print0`

  This finds all files in the current directory with `dog` in their name and prints them out in a nul-separated list.  Since the nul character is one of the few not allowed in a file name, this is safe.  If you want a case-insensitive match (so that `Dog` is matched as well), replace `-name` with `-iname`.
- `grep -zc .`

  This reads in a nul-separated list and counts the lines.

  - `-z` tells `grep` that the input is nul-separated
  - `-c` tells `grep` to suppress normal output and count the number of matches
  - `.` tells `grep` to match anything.